# Kotlin read variable and post yes or no answer

Tags: kotlin, estimote, telemetry

I use Java and Kotlin for personal projects with little experience and I might use your help with this one. What I am trying to do is to read telemetry data (temperature, pressure, light level) from Estimote beacon. I have already managed to put & update values into textviews.

Now I would like to get IF conditions at this point (later I will try to save & upload them to Firebase database). Basically I want to check if one of the telemetry values is higher or less than Double number. Eg. if the light level is below 6 lux, write "Less then 6!", if more "More than 6!"

```
        val scanner = EstimoteBluetoothScannerFactory(applicationContext).getSimpleScanner()
        val scanHandler = scanner.estimoteTelemetryFullScan()
                .withBalancedPowerMode()
                .withOnPacketFoundAction {
                    var temperature: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temperature)
                    temperature.setText("Temperature: ${it.temperatureInCelsiusDegrees}")
                    var magnetometer: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.magnetometer)
                    magnetometer.setText("Magnetometer: ${it.magnetometer}")
                    var pressure: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pressure)
                    pressure.setText("Pressure: ${it.pressure}")
                    var ambientLight: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ambientLight)
                    ambientLight.setText("Ambient Light: ${it.ambientLightInLux}")
                    var motionState: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.motionState)
                    motionState.setText("Motion State: ${it.motionState}")
                }
                .start()

    if(ambientLight > 6) {
        var checkLight: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.checkLight)
        checkLight.setText("More than 6!")
    }else{
        var checkLight: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.checkLight)
        checkLight.setText("Less than 6!")
    }
```

This code does not update the textview value

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, but I'm pretty sure that the code to update the textview needs to be inside the `withOnPacketFound` block.

Comment: Worked like charm! I had to change only variable check into direct reference to the SDK (it.ambientLightInLux > 6)